# PyMongo: AttributeErrors for existing attributes in class _cmessage

Tags: python, database, mongodb, exception, pymongo

I use pymongo to connect to my databases on a mongodb server. I set everything up and used a simple tutorial to start with basic things in pymongo. I ended up writting this into a python file:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from random import randint

client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017) #Class from PyMongo module
db = client["rothe_plana"]

# Initialize database settings for employers and events collections:
employersCollect = db["employers"]
eventsCollect = db["events"]

#-----------------------------------------------------
#Employer database managment:
#-----------------------------------------------------

#Inserts passed dictionary objects of employer profiles:
def insertNewEmployer(new_employer_profile):
    while True:
        try:
            readyProfile = new_employer_profile.copy()
            readyProfile['employer_id'] = randint(100, 999)
            employersCollect.insert_one()
        except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError:
            continue
        break

def getListOfEmployerIDs():
    pass #get employer ids to identify and render template elements.

# -----------------------------------------------------
# Events database managment:
# -----------------------------------------------------

#Inserts passed dictionary objects of event data:
def insertNewEvent(new_event_data):
    while True:
        try:
            readyEventData = new_employer_profile.copy()
            readyEventData['event_id'] = randint(10000000, 99999999)
            employersCollect.insert_one()
        except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError:
            continue
        break
```

But if I run this I get an exception:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1664, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1658, in main
        globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
      File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1068, in run
        pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
      File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
        exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
      File "C:/Users/thoma/OneDrive/Projects_For_The_Web/Fliesen Rothe/PlanA/Pyramid_PlanA/pyramid_plana/datadbhandler.py", line 1, in <module>
        from pymongo import MongoClient
      File "C:\Users\thoma\OneDrive\Projects_For_The_Web\Fliesen Rothe\PlanA\Pyramid_PlanA\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
        from pymongo.collection import ReturnDocument
      File "C:\Users\thoma\OneDrive\Projects_For_The_Web\Fliesen Rothe\PlanA\Pyramid_PlanA\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 29, in <module>
        from pymongo import (common,
      File "C:\Users\thoma\OneDrive\Projects_For_The_Web\Fliesen Rothe\PlanA\Pyramid_PlanA\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\message.py", line 654, in <module>
        _op_msg_uncompressed = _cmessage._op_msg
    AttributeError: module 'pymongo._cmessage' has no attribute '_op_msg'
```

Since I certainly did not touch the Pymongo module code, I am doing something wrong in my code above. Also the web didn't bring up any results so is there a clear explanation for this?

***EDIT:*** I had a closer look into the files that were provided by the above error. And I can see that the attribute in the specified class actually do exist. So that is quite strange. Even if I comment the dependent line out of pymongo, there is another AtrributeError for the same class.

Answer (score 1):

I finally resolved the problem. It turned out that the permissions in my filesystem were not handled right.
I originally installed PyMongo via PyCharm (`pip install pymongo`). But this just does not work (no idea why) but I finally uninstalled pymongo from the virtual environment and installed it manually again via PowerShell in the virtual environment:

```
python -m pip install pymongo
```

Restarting PyCharm and running the project did bring up no errors anymore. Hope this may help others with this problem